# AWS - EC2 and RDS MultiAZ performance for Laravel application

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I've set up a web application using AWS services:

- Loadbalancer to sit in front of application
- Autoscaling group with single EC2 instance as app server (running Apache, PHP / Laravel) t2.micro
- RDS: MySQL 8.0.16 set up as MultiAZ t2.micro

Everything works - but it is very slow. I looked at the monitoring stats, and neither the database nor the app server instance looks particularly under pressure (CPU at 2% only).

I checked the Availability Zones for the DB and the EC2 instance, and they are not the same (eu-west-1a and eu-west-1b), and I saw some other threads recommending that DB and app server be in same AZ for performance reasons.

I am going to try this to see if it improves performance. However, if I set this up so that DB and app servers are in the same AZ, it seems like I am losing the benefit of having the service set up as MultiAZ in the first place, if all my EC2 instances have to be in the same AZ as the database.

So, how can I have MultiAZ app servers AND good performance/connectivity with RDS?

Comment: Well, if both DB and EC2 instance are critical to the applicatoin functioning, then you gain no benefit by putting them in separate AZs. If you are looking for redundancy through AZs then all critical infrastructure must be duplicated across the AZs. In your case, you would need DB and EC2 in both AZs. This comes with a whole host of issues around synchronizing your databases and configuring when/how to failover to a separate AZs DB.

Comment: Are you able to profile your application and see where the performance hit is? Even across AZs the performance should not be effected so substantially (if noticeable at all). Is the RDS private rather than public?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Yes, RDS is private. MultiAZ with read replica in different AZ. Havent used MulitAZ before, so not sure how to profile to find bottleneck

Comment: Profile in your application to attempt to see whether its the application or DB. If you're looking for a free tool then Xdebug could work, from experience I have used https://blackfire.io/ before to profile as its easy to visualise (it costs monthly but you could use a free trial just to debug this)

Comment: Additional information request from your primary RDS site. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information ( using a support ticket to request), if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.